# Get Domain Group id using REST API in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, domain

We have a SharePoint 2013 On premise environments and having the **Domain Groups** with the Names contains **SPECIAL characters** as below.
[image]

I want get the **Domain Group Id**  and  assign **READ** permission using Rest api

I tried to get the ID of the Group as below

```
_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('(Role)x$Customer$2838')?$select=id
```

and Got the `Group cannot be found.` error.

I tried with replacing the special characters as below, But no luck

[image]

Comment: You cannot get domain groups from SharePoint as they are domain groups. `_api/web/sitegroups` only returns SharePoint groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the solution  from the post [How to add an AD group to a SP group using REST api?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121211/how-to-add-an-ad-group-to-a-sp-group-using-rest-api)

```
"/_api/web/siteusers?$select=id,Title&$filter=PrincipalType eq 4 and Title eq '(Role)x$Customer$2838'";
```

Answer (score -1):

to get sharepoint group id using rest having special character in group name.

```
var groupName = encodeURIComponent('(Role)x$Customer$2838');
_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('+groupName+')?$select=id
```

And you cannot get domain group direct using the sharepoint rest api.